# Dealing with shorthand characters in regular expressions

Tags: regex, nfa

I have to built a NFA from a regular expression and then go through a text and found matching patterns.

I used Thompson's construction to build the NFA when the expression contains only the alphabet characters, `*`, `|` and `.` (Cleene star, union and concatenation respectively).

But how to deal with shorthand characters in the regular expression such as `\d` can be random digit from `0` to `9` and `\a` - random letter?

I sure can just replace it in the regular expression as `(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)` but I highly doubt that is what I am supposed to do.

Comment: can you please add some code so we can help you in your problem?

Comment: Not right now..

Comment: But i was guided by this [link]( https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html )

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in an NFA, a transition from state A to state B that accepts any of N characters is fine, it is just a short way of writing down N transitions from state A to state B that each accept 1 character.

So for the purposes of your translation, you can just treat `\d` as a single character. If you need to, you can expand it into 10 separate transitions after the fact.